# How to asynchronously create COM components in an ASP.NET WebForms application?

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, com

I am attempting to asynchronously create COM components an ASP.NET WebForms application.

I seem to be running into a conflict.

In order to run Async methods I need to specify the `@Page` directive: `Async="True"`

```
<%@ Page Inherits="HealthCheck.HealthCheck" Title="Health Check" Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="Site.Master" CodeBehind="HealthCheck.aspx.vb" Async="true" %>
```

When I do this, I receive the following message:

```
Apartment threaded components can only be created on pages with an  page directive.
```

That leads me to specify the `@Page` directive: `AspCompat="True"`

Which results in:

```
Async attribute cannot be set to true when AspCompat mode is enabled.
```

It seems to be a catch 22.  Does anyone have any suggestions for how I could do this?  Note, please don't feel limited to using VB in your answers.  I am fluent in both VB and C# and will happily accept answers of either.  Thanks!

The code:

```
Private Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    DetailedCheck()
End Sub

Private Async Sub DetailedCheck()
    Dim lstComponentTasks As New List(Of Task(Of Component))
    For Each key As String In ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys()
        lstComponentTasks.Add(GetComponentTaskAsync(key))
    Next

    Await Task.WhenAll(lstComponentTasks)
    Dim lstComponents As List(Of Component) = (From lstComponentTask In lstComponentTasks Select lstComponentTask.Result).ToList()

    If lstComponents.Any(Function(x) x.ResponseStatusCode = 555) Then
        Response.StatusCode = 555
    End If

    lvComponents.DataSource = lstComponents.OrderBy(Function(com) com.Name)
    lvComponents.DataBind()
End Sub

Private Function GetComponentTaskAsync(name As String) As Task(Of Component)
    Return Task.Run(Of Component)(Function()
                                      Return GetComponent(name)
                                  End Function)
End Function

Private Function GetComponent(name As String) As Component
    Dim component As New Component With {.Name = name}
    Try
        Dim objComponent = Server.CreateObject(name)
        component.Status = "VALID"
    Catch ex As Exception
        component.ResponseStatusCode = 555
        component.Status = ex.Message
    End Try
    Return component
End Function

Public Class Component
    Property Name() As String
    Property Status() As String
    Property ResponseStatusCode() As Integer
End Class
```

Comment: A thought I had was to possibly recreate my project an an MVC application.  Not sure, but perhaps that would resolve my asynchronous woes...?

Comment: Created an MVC application. Using AsyncController. Using delegate OnCompleted event.  All works well until this error `Apartment threaded components can only be created on pages with an <%@ Page aspcompat=true %>`  I didn't think MVC had page directives.  Hmm